# Using a tunnel to connect to another PC on my home network

Tags: ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

How can I connect to another pc on my home network using a tunnel ?

I have an ssh tunnel setup to my PC at home and I use it as an additional level of security when I conect over unencrypted access points.

Typically I use firefox that connects over Sockets Host to the tunnel I setup as follows:
 ***ssh -f -ND 9993 -p 443 nobody@website.servebeer.com***

On my home network which I acccess via the tunnel I have several PC's running private web-servers ... example the PC that I am tunneling to is on a local network, 192.168.1.x

Is it possible to get access to a PC, example 192.168.1.23:8080 , over this tunnel ?

How can I gain access this way from the remote PC ?

Thanks
DD

Answer (score 0):

I think the port setup is ok. But your connection to the internet should have an static IP, or some sort of DNS service, so you can find your computer. Then said router should be servicing the port `8080` to the `192.168.1.x`.

Back in 05(or so) I used to use `noip.com` which at the used an app on your pc and gave you a url like `www.noip.com/doctordoodad` which when pinged resolved to your pc.